# Windows boot screen, still showing already removed os

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-7, windows-server-2008

i had a triple boot of windows 7,8 and server 2008r2 on my machine.
the 3 os were installed on different partition in same hdd.
I formated the partition on which windows 8 was installed.
then i changed the default windows to boot to 7.

When i turn on my machine, i still get the selection of selecting windows 8 os.
how to completely remove the windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `msconfig.exe`, go to the boot tab and remove the Windows 8 entry.

[image]